# How to move div background image, when push menu is active?

Tags: jquery, html, css

**How To solve The Issue:**

how i can move my div background image, when push menu is active...
i am using div css like

```
.webcam-bg {
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-image: url("../images/bg.png");
    background-size: cover;
    height: auto;
}
```

if am not using **background-attachment: fixed;** ,this div background was moved when push menu is active... but i need **background-attachment: fixed;** position to move right when push menu is active....?

Any one suggest me or help me to achieve the problem..

Comment: are you comfortable with javascript ? or jq ?

Answer (score 0):

To move the background image you can use either [background-origin](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/background-origin/) or more likely [background-position](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/background-position/)

I am not sure what you mean by "push menu".
I assume this is an element with class `.push-menu`, if it is modified by a class `.active` and is a sibling of your `.webcam-bg` element,  then this is what you can write

```
.push-menu.active ~ .webcam-bg {
      background-position: ... ;
}
```